# How to call javascript function each time user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to call a javascript function each time Facebook updates their feed for a user (when he scrolls). Any idea how I can do that?

This does not work:

```
if (document.body.scrollTop > 30) {
        addArt();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `window.addEventListener("scroll", addArt());` might work

Comment: There's an onscroll event if I remember correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an `onscroll` function:

```
window.onscroll = function() { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach it to the `window`'s `scroll` event listener. I have wrapped it inside an `onload` event, so that it gets executed after the document is loaded.

```
window.onload = function () {
  window.onscroll = function () {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 30) {
      addArt();
    }
  };
};
```

Or if you are using jQuery, use:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 30) {
      addArt();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, you can use this function to run code every time the user scrolls

`$( window ).scroll(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
        addArt();
    }
});`

`window.onscroll = function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 30) {
        addArt();
    }
};`

edit: added none jquery version

Comment: And it they're not using jQuery?

Comment: @GordonM Answer edited to have a none jquery version